# "A year older than Mary at school" or "a year above Mary at school"

Tags: word-usage

I have a question about children's grades at school.

When two children whose age you don't know go to the same elementary school, and one is a third-grader and the other is a second-grader, which sentence can you say?

> Lisa is a year **older than** Mary at school.
>
> Lisa is a year **above** Mary at school.

Comment: Your use of "year" here is a bit "loose". What you mean in *Lisa is in **the year-group** for pupils a year older than Mary*. Most native speakers would probably use ***above*** in your cited context, but because you've explicitly included ***at school*** I think it would be perfectly okay (and would definitely be correctly *understood*) if you used ***older than***. Obviously if you wanted to say Lisa's *age* was a year more than Mary's, there would be no reason to mention ***at school*** (unless this was to specifically identify the Mary at school, rather than another Mary somewhere else).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is correct:

> Lisa is a year above Mary at school.

**Older** would mean she is literally older by one year. She certainly might be, but we would not say so with **at school** because age does not depend on the context.

This would also be correct and perhaps more common:

> Lisa is a year *ahead of* Mary at school.

Comment: In AmE, one could use "grade" in place of "year": Lisa is a grade ahead of Mary.